# Developing a generalized code to obtain the impulse response and the output for a given input for any LTIC in MATLAB and then plotting it

Tags: matlab

Equation of dynamics are given by the differential equations

System 1.1 : $\quad\quad (D+2)x(t) = (3D +5) r(t)$

System 1.2 : $\quad\quad D(D+2) x(t) = (D+4) r(t)$

System 1.3 : $\quad\quad (D^2 +2D+1) x(t) = D r(t)$

We have to write a code which can obtain its impulse response and its output then plot both of them. I have never worked on Matlab before so i have no idea how to do this.
I have tried solving this on paper but on Matlab i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Please. Show us  your "paper " developments.

Comment: I cant show all of what i have done because its in my rough notebook. But for example for system 1.3 impulse response h(t)=(1-t)e^(-t) u(t) and final output is x(t) = t e^-t

Comment: Please. Have a look at https://es.mathworks.com/help/control/getstart/linear-lti-models.html

Comment: I did but i am still very confused as most of these models are for discrete time systems and not continuous time systems